# How you can convert JsonArray from String of JsonArray format in Java?

Tags: java, json

Now, I try to link that fullcalendar in jQuery UI and Database(Oracle 10g). But, a problem has occurred.

I want to parse that JsonArray from String of JsonArray format. 
ex)
**String of JsonArray format**

```
-> String jsonArrayStr="[{test1:'test',test2:2,test3:'test3'},
                         {test1:'test',test2:2,test3:'test3'}, 
                         {test1:'test',test2:2,test3:'test3'}]";
```

**String of JsonArray format->JsonArray**

```
->JSONArray jsonArray = **(?)**
```

How you can convert JsonArray from String of JsonArray format in Java?

Comment: Using one of the numerous JSON parsers in Java?

Comment: my suggestion is the famous [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this using [this](http://json.org/java/) library

```
String jsonArrayStr="[{test1:'test',test2:2,test3:'test3'},{test1:'test',test2:2,test3:'test3'}, {test1:'test',test2:2,test3:'test3'}]";
JSONArray jrr = new JSONArray(jsonArrayStr);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to your method. but Error occurred that "The constructor JSONArray(String) is undefined".

Comment: Are you using the library which I linked in my answer? [https://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/detail?name=org.json-20120521.jar&can=2&q=](link)

Comment: I succeeded that convert to JsonArray from String of JsonArray format. And I try to convert that JsonObject from JsonObject in JsonArray. Could you explain about this method?

Comment: No you cannot convert jsonarray to jsonobject as contents with in `{}` are jsonobject and `[]` and these are jsonarray you need to change the structure. the things are key and value pairs like `{key : value  }` in jsonobject and and `[val, val, val]` in json array.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing me with your tags: "java" and "jquery", did you mean "JavaScript"? Because Java has no relation with jQuery....

**If you mean JavaScript, this may be your solution:**

```
var jsonArrayStr = "[{test1:'test',test2:2,test3:'test3'},{test1:'test',test2:2,test3:'test3'}, {test1:'test',test2:2,test3:'test3'}]";
var jsonArray = JSON.parse( jsonArrayStr );
```

**If you mean really Java, try the following code:**

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonArrayStr);
```

*Dependencies:*

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

Comment: maybe tags are confusing but OP does ask `How you can convert JsonArray from String of JsonArray format in Java?`

Comment: maybe he doesn't know the difference? Anyway it's confusing!

Comment: Thank you. but I have been called server form Data in JavaScript for client. This data is value of String.