# How to parse a string to add line feed and tab after a curly brace/square bracket in java

Tags: java, json

Just want to ask what is the best way to transform a json string from:

```
{"scenario":{"title":"User1_PrivatePrint_1Pg_Duplex_BW_A4","description":"Private Print 1 Page Duplex B/W A4 Job","sequences":[{"spiMethod":"notifyAuthenticationStatus","parameter":{"AuthenticationStatus":{"AuthenticationState":"Authenticated","AuthenticationAttributes":{"UserAttributes":{"UserId":"user1","CustomAttribute":"Role1","UserType":"Co"}}}}},{"spiMethod":"validateJobCreation","parameter":{"JobCreationConditions":{"JobAttributes":{"StoredDocumentAttributes":{"UserJobType":"PrivateSpool"},"UserJobType":"PrivatePrint","JobAttributesInPrinting":{"ColorMode":"BW"}}}}}]}}
```

to this one:

```
{
"scenario":{
    "title":"User1_PrivatePrint_1Pg_Duplex_BW_A4",
    "description":"Private Print 1 Page Duplex B/W A4 Job",
    "sequences":[
        {
            "spiMethod":"notifyAuthenticationStatus",
            "parameter":{
                "AuthenticationStatus":{
                    "AuthenticationState":"Authenticated",
                    "AuthenticationAttributes":{
                        "UserAttributes":{
                            "UserId":"user1",
                            "CustomAttribute":"Role1",
                            "UserType":"Co"
                        }                            
                    }                        
                }                    
            } 
        },
        {
            "spiMethod":"validateJobCreation",
            "parameter":{
                "JobCreationConditions":{
                    "JobAttributes":{
                        "StoredDocumentAttributes":{
                            "UserJobType":"PrivateSpool"
                        },
                        "UserJobType":"PrivatePrint",
                        "JobAttributesInPrinting":{
                            "ColorMode":"BW"
                        }                            
                    }                        
                }                    
            }                
        }
    ]
}
```

}

i searched online and found that i can use regular expressions but since i am new to java i do not know to use these expressions.

thank you.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use regex in this case. There is no easy way to do this. You have to do it in a hard way.

Comment: Maybe use external tool. Notepad++ has nice plugin for this (JSTool). Just use JSFormat on your JSon data.

Comment: Actually i need to save the string in a file so i cannot use NotePad++ to do it. it should be already edited when i open the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to format your JSon string with [GSon](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library

```
String data = "{\"scenario\":{\"title\":\"User1_PrivatePrint_1Pg_Duplex_BW_A4\",\"description\":\"Private Print 1 Page Duplex B/W A4 Job\",\"sequences\":[{\"spiMethod\":\"notifyAuthenticationStatus\",\"parameter\":{\"AuthenticationStatus\":{\"AuthenticationState\":\"Authenticated\",\"AuthenticationAttributes\":{\"UserAttributes\":{\"UserId\":\"user1\",\"CustomAttribute\":\"Role1\",\"UserType\":\"Co\"}}}}},{\"spiMethod\":\"validateJobCreation\",\"parameter\":{\"JobCreationConditions\":{\"JobAttributes\":{\"StoredDocumentAttributes\":{\"UserJobType\":\"PrivateSpool\"},\"UserJobType\":\"PrivatePrint\",\"JobAttributesInPrinting\":{\"ColorMode\":\"BW\"}}}}}]}}";

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

JsonElement element = parser.parse(data);
String formattedJSon = gson.toJson(element);
System.out.println(formattedJSon);
```

Output:

```
{
  "scenario": {
    "title": "User1_PrivatePrint_1Pg_Duplex_BW_A4",
    "description": "Private Print 1 Page Duplex B/W A4 Job",
    "sequences": [
      {
        "spiMethod": "notifyAuthenticationStatus",
        "parameter": {
          "AuthenticationStatus": {
            "AuthenticationState": "Authenticated",
            "AuthenticationAttributes": {
              "UserAttributes": {
                "UserId": "user1",
                "CustomAttribute": "Role1",
                "UserType": "Co"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "spiMethod": "validateJobCreation",
        "parameter": {
          "JobCreationConditions": {
            "JobAttributes": {
              "StoredDocumentAttributes": {
                "UserJobType": "PrivateSpool"
              },
              "UserJobType": "PrivatePrint",
              "JobAttributesInPrinting": {
                "ColorMode": "BW"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. what if i don't use the gson library or any third party library? just org.json?

Comment: Don't make your life (and people who will maintain your code) harder. Use libraries which are known by all like GSon, Jackson as often as you can. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: i tried using gson but it added parameter "map" in the output string. example: {
  "map": {
    "PrintingPaperStatus": {
      "map": {
        "Plex": "Duplex",
        "PrintingPaperState": "PaperFeed",
        "JobAttributes": {
          "map": {
            "JobLogJobId": "685",
            "JobRequestUser": {
              "map": {
                "UserAttributes": {
                  "map": {                                        this is just a snippet of the json string because it is too long

Comment: @user3388797 How was your input looked like? Can you post it on http://pastebin.com/ and share link?

Comment: This JSon string works fine for me. I don't see any additional "map" parameters.

Comment: it's working now for me, i forgot to use the parser. thank you for your help Pshemo. One more question, is there a way i can parse the json string back to its original form without using the JsonParser from gson?

Comment: You can use similar code as in my answer. Just replace `new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();` with default Gson object `new Gson()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
System.out.println(json);
```

Thanks to [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-enable-pretty-print-json-output-gson/)

Comment: thank you for this. is it possible to not use any third party library?

Comment: Do not mention it. Sorry, but unfortunately, other ways I do not know.

Comment: I saw your question to Pshemo and would like to help you. See this screenshot (100% correct for your json-fragment): http://pumpshooter.com/dUMlRSLK

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to my problem.
Please refer to the link.

[How you can convert JsonArray from String of JsonArray format in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089791/how-you-can-convert-jsonarray-from-string-of-jsonarray-format-in-java/22089835?noredirect=1#comment33525023_22089835)

Maybe You will need to use that JSONArray and JSONObject.